# Como adequar APP que utiliza protocolo TCP a conexão 3g?

Tags: android, app, conexão

Estou desenvolvendo um APP para Android e utilizei conexão TCP direta e também requisições HTTP.

Para o perfeito funcionamento do meu aplicativo estando conectado em uma rede 3g ao invés do WiFi, preciso modificar meu código? Ou a conexão 3g é gerenciada pelo sistema operacional Android?

Como a conexão 3g envia e recebe pacotes TCP/IP para um servidor conectado a internet? Como é o funcionamento exatamente?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ao nível da aplicação, normalmente, não temos que nos preocupar com o tipo de ligação de dados que está disponível no dispositivo.

O sistema operativo é quem tem essa preocupação e gestão.

**Respondendo diretamente à tua pergunta:**
Não, não tens que modificar o teu código, tudo deverá funcionar corretamente.

---

#Preocupação a ter aplicação

Na aplicação, temos que nos preocupar sim, em verificar se existe alguma ligação para permitir e/ou realizar operações que a requerem:

###Permissões

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

###Exemplo de verificação

Com estas permissões podemos consultar no dispositivo, qual o estado a ligação:

```
public void myClickHandler(View view) {
    ...
    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) 
        getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        // Temos ligação, continuar
    } else {
        // Não temos ligação, informar utilizador
    }

    // ...
}
```

Este exemplo e outros podem ser consultados e analisados em detalhe na página de documentação para:

[Connecting to the Network | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>

---

#TCP/IP sobre 3G

TCP/IP está presente em dispositivos que disponham do serviço GPRS que por sua vez se encontra disponível nas tecnologias de comunicações móveis a partir da 2ª Geração.

Dado que um dispositivo com suporte e a fazer uso de TCP/IP recebe pelo menos um endereço IP, a comunicação a partir do mesmo é igual à comunicação em qualquer PC ou servidor ligado à Internet.

Leitura relacionada:

- [RFC 3481 - TCP over Second (2.5G) and Third (3G) Generation Wireless Networks](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3481)
- [Wikipedia: General packet radio service (GPRS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Packet_Radio_Service)
- [Wikipedia: 3G](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3G)

<sup>**Nota:** As particularidades sobre o funcionamento de todos estes serviços e protocolos já fica fora do escopo deste site, pelo que não vou elaborar mais sobre o assunto nesta resposta.</sup>